# How to give selected value to option with no value - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a select witch is generated dynamically, it looks like this

```
    <select id="elem">
        <option value="3">value 1</option>
        <option value="6">value 2</option>
        <option value="18">value 3</option>
        <option>value 4</option>
    </select>
```

The last option has no value. I am trying to make the select to display the "value 4" option on the first position when the page is loaded, using javascript

Here is what i tried in javascript

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem"),
        selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex];

    if ( selectedNode.value === "" ) {
        selectedNode.setAttribute('selected','');
    }
```

How can it be done ?

Comment: `selectedNode.innerHTML === "value 4"`

Comment: Don't you mean `selectedNode.setAttribute('selected','selected');`?

Comment: Why not have the server determine the one it's creating without a value and set it selected there? What you are doing in JS is looking for the value that is already selected and then deselecting it if the value is empty. If you want to select the option with no value you would be better off looping through the options collection and `setAttribute("selected","selected")` on the one with `value == ""`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When no `value` is specified, the `value` will be the text. You can use `hasAttribute` to check for the `value` as well:

```
var select = document.getElementById("elem");

for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (!select.options[i].hasAttribute('value')) {
        select.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/682Ap/1/

Comment: Is there any other way you can think of checking if option has value attribute?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh -- I updated the answer, you can use `hasAttribute`

Comment: Great - I think this is better approach. Losing my grip on JS selectors, have been doing jQuery for too long.

Answer (score 0):

several ways to do it. if you need to find the option first, the code would be like this . It's looking for an option with non numeric value - unfortunately if you omit the value the text of the option becomes its value

```
var sel = document.getElementById("elem");
var index = 0;
for(var i = 0;i<sel.options.length;i++){
  if (isNaN(sel.options[i].value))
    index = i;
}
```

if you know the index, you can set the selected option as

```
sel.selectedIndex = index;
```